# Изменение расположения при position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Когда я указываю position: fixed для блока он съезжает. Я не могу найти этой проблемы, не говоря уже о решении.

Вот изображение с блоком без указания position.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот без

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*(сниппет лучше открывать на всю страницу)*

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
.container{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
header {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
main{
    width: 30000px;
}
.header__content{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.header__content ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.header__content li{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header__content li a{
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
@media (min-width:1200px){
    .container{
        width: 1170px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){
    .container{
        width: 970px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .container {
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
<div class="header__main">

<div class="container">
  <div class="header__content">
    <div class="header__logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="#" alt="brand">
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What I do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</header>

<main style="height: 150vh">
  asd
</main>
```

Comment: Можете ли вы выложить код?

Comment: Сделайте у родителя     position: relative;

Comment: это сделает мой хедер прикрепленным к верхуэкрана?

Comment: body{  position: relative;  } header{ top: 0; }

Comment: `pisition fixed` выводит элемент из обычного потока следования как это пишут в заумных документах. Надо всего лишь добавить `padding-top` для `body` равный высоте менюшки, либо `margin-top` для `main`. [ссылка](https://webref.ru/css/position)

Comment: как это сделать если высота хэдера нефиксирована?

Comment: @andreymal А почему вы следующую правку отклонили?

Comment: @0xdb она оказалась по сути аналогична моей, но моя, как я понял, оказалась на несколько секунд быстрее и имеет доведённое до ума оформление в отличие от отклонённой. Не успел человек, бывает)

Comment: body{ position: relative; } header{ top: 0; } не помогло. Элемент всеравно сдвигается вправо